# Highlight autocomplete suggestions Drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a text field in a form, with autocomplete on. It works very well, but I cannot manage to find a way to highlight the letters in the suggested works. I found this hack in the autocomplete library (general, no Drupal related), but don't know if it applies or how to apply it. I would like the same effect:

http://output.jsbin.com/ezifi/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) Module. May b this help you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! However, I had to do the following, hacking the code, to make it work as I wanted: 1) delete the "the @term termi will be added" because it tried to add new non-existing content. 2) hack the code of *.js so it didn't trigger when mouse down or mouse up, just when I hit some key. 3) Add t() to the not found message. What I don't understand is that such a basic feature is not incorporated into the core autocomplete.js, and also don't understand why this module Autocomplete Deluxe is abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [tutorial](http://complexdan.com/passing-custom-arguments-drupal-7-autocomplete/). It is a small gem in which I have found the solution to this problem and [this another one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174777/results-of-autocomplete-field-in-form-depending-on-another-field-drupal-7).

Basically, I use the hook callback function **mymodule_formName_autocomplete ($type, $text)** and there I can do **drupal_json_output($output_string)** where *$output_string*, based on the string query *$text* accepts any HTML label, so I can highlight at convenience by just using PHP, which is very powerful.